MTG interaction between Flickerwisp and Thassa, Deep-Dwelling
Flickerwisp reads

When Flickerwisp enters, exile another target permanent. Return that card to the battlefield under its owner's control at the beginning of the next end step.

Thassa, Deep-Dwelling reads

At the beginning of your end step, exile up to one other target creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.

Can I exile another creature with Flickerwisp's ETB effect (e.g. Ravenous Chupacabra), and have the Chupacabra come back at the beginning of the end step for Thassa to blink it again? More generally, this is for any blink "until next endstep" and "at beginning of end step" triggers, e.g. Eerie Interlude and Soulherder as well. Asking for my Esper blink deck.

Minor note: the text actually printed on a card is essentially irrelevant; all that matters is the Gatherer text which does state "at the beginning of the next end step" so your Flickerwisp assumption is correct.

I've taken the liberty and updated the card text to the Oracle version. As Phillip Kendall said, the printed text is not relevant.

@Hackworth Without input from OP, you may have edited away one of the main points of confusion. The printed wording could confuse a new player into thinking that "the beginning of the end step" happens before "the end of the turn". With your edit, it's now crystal clear that both triggers occur at the beginning of the end step. This distinction belongs in your answer, not in an edit to the question. Recommend rolling it back.

@Rainbolt The original question said I'm assuming this means beginning of end step, from the errata., so I didn't see confusion about the wording being the core of the question.

No, you can't blink the same creature twice in the same turn with that combo.
Flickerwisp returns the creature it exiled as a delayed triggered ability, specifically when the next end step starts. The beginning of an end step is a singular event, and by that time, the Chupacabra has not already returned; its return goes on the stack and has to resolve first. Thassa's ability triggers at the same time, but since Thassa has to target one of your creatures to even go on the stack, that creature has to exist on the battlefield already to be a legal target. Chupacabra cannot have returned by that point, so you could only target Flickerwisp or some other creature you're controlling.
The best you can do is to arrange Thassa's and Flickerwisps's abilities such that the Chupacabra returns, then Thassa blinks Flickerwisp, and the returning Flickerwisp exiles Chupacabra again so that Chupacabra returns during your opponent's end step.
